# Postgres: Create database with superuser and password

Tags: postgresql

I created a Postgres database this way:

```
createdb massive
```

Then I added a role:

```
sudo -iu postgres
psql -d massive
CREATE ROLE rob WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
```

I quit `psql` with `\q`, then `exit` user `postgres`.

Now I try to login:

```
psql -U rob -d massive -h localhost -W
```

When entering `password` at the password prompt, I get this:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "rob"
```

Update:

`\l`in `psql` returns this:

```
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 massive   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

`\du` returns this:

```
                             List of roles
 Role name |                   Attributes                   | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication | {}
 rob       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB              | {}
```

Comment: If you specify `encrypted` the value of the password that you supply (the `'password'` part) must already be encrypted. As you supply the password in plain text in the `CREATE ROLE` statement you must remove the `encrypted` keyword.

Comment: Tried it without `ENCRYPTED` keyword but still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you check your pg_hba.conf to make sure that password authentication is an accepted authentication method?

Comment: password was not listed. I added this line: `local   all             all                                     password` and ran `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`. But still no success.

Comment: I cannot login to using `psql` as `postgres:postgres` also.

Comment: Logging in using 0xDBE from JetBrains works fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `ENCRYPTED` is silently ignored if the password doesn't begin with `md5` by the looks. It still gets hashed. That's a bit "special". To see, query `pg_shadow` after changing password with/without `ENCRYPTED` keyword.

Comment: You know that `CREATEDB CREATEROLE` is redundant if you specify `SUPERUSER` right? Because a `SUPERUSER` has full global rights on the entire system anyway?

Comment: Tried it all again in another VM as described in the question and it works.